# how to call index.php on startup with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have searching around it..but not found solution.so i posted this question.
i have a `.htaccess` file.i am trying to redirect website on `index.php`.
example: when user type `demo.org/demo2/` then url redirect to `demo.org/demo2/index.php`.
**NOTE** : `index.php` is inside `demo2` directory.

`.htaccess file:`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
php_value memory_limit 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

problem is url is not redirecting.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to confirm that with your current set up, apache is serving up the contents of index.php, and you just want the url itself to redirect?

Comment: yes,i am trying to redirect the url itself.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect. If a directory has an index file (html or php) then when someone browses to that directory they will be taken to the index file automatically??

Comment: Based on your comments, it sounds like your Apache isn't configured to run PHP somehow, but since it opens well when you open the file by hand - could you verify for me, where is this .htaccess file you've listed above relative to `demo2`?

Comment: `.htaccess` file is located in `demo2` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something along these lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo2/?$
    RewriteRule ^$ http://demo.org/demo2/index.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: no man..if i type only `demo.org/demo2/` then it gives warning..`Directory Listing Denied

This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.` but if i type `demo.org/demo2/index.php` then it work fine.

Comment: That result is with or without my suggestion?

Comment: this is the main problem i face it.and by the way this problem is still i facing. i change my .htaccess file with your code.but still it is not working.

Comment: I made an update, I forgot the slashes. And I have confirmed this works on my Apache 2.2

Comment: thanks for your help.but this is not work in `index.php` then i add `index.htm` and it's work.but still url is not redirecting.

Comment: it is neccesary to restart apache server?

Comment: You do not need to restart your Apache server for .htaccess changes to take affect, but I do want to make sure you added my suggestion to your .htaccess file. From your comment is sounds like you put it in the index.php file.